How can I attach a debugger to a dotnet console application in VS Code?
I've been at this for a couple hours now and I continue to be baffled at how intractable this is. I'm simply trying to attach a debugger to a running console application that I'm developing in VS Code, and while the attach appears to work just fine, I can't get a single breakpoint to be hit because VS Code claims that no symbols have been loaded for this document. I'm using the following launch.json configuration:
{
    "name": ".NET Core Attach",
    "type": "coreclr",
    "request": "attach",
    "processId": "${command:pickProcess}",
    "justMyCode": true,
    "symbolOptions": {
        "searchPaths": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/net8.0"
        ]
    },
    "logging": {
        "engineLogging": true,
        "trace": true
    }
}

I've verified that the build assets are going into the correct folder as specified in the configuration and that the build includes the pdb files. I've also both built and run the app using -c Debug. So far none of this has made any difference. I'm sure there is something dumb that I'm overlooking, but I seem to be incapable of finding it. Any help would be enormously appreciated.
